# Transferring Variables Between Classes In Java

Tags: java, android, xml, variables, xml-parsing

I have created and XML parser that acquires the data in the description tag.  I am attempting to pass it to a web view because it has HTML formatting.  I am new to Java and I don't really know how to do that.

This is what I have in the first class:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,Webscreen.class);
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("keyDescription", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getDescription());
 intent.putExtras(bundle);
 startActivity(intent);
```

This is what I have so far in the second class:

```
public static final String URL = "";
private static final String TAG = "WebscreenClass";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webscreen);

    if(URL == null && URL == ""){
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.layout.webscreen);
        String htmlString = keyDescription;
        webview.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }else{
        String turl = getIntent().getStringExtra(URL);
        Log.i(TAG, " URL = "+turl);

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        WebSettings websettings = webview.getSettings();
        websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        setContentView(webview);


        // Simplest usage: An exception won't be thrown if there is a page-load error
        webview.loadUrl(turl);
    }
}
```

I am using the if else statement because I use this class to load web pages as well.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second activity just retrieve the Extra Data.

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Comment: How would I get the description from that? Do I do this:
`String htmlString = bundle.getString("keyDescription");`

Comment: Yes Sir... "keyDescription" is the key you mapped the description to in the bundle in the first activity.

Comment: I did this and it says: bundle cannot be resolved.  I put the code here:

`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webscreen);
        //String keyDescription = savedInstanceState.getString("keyDescription");
        
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        
  if(URL == null || URL == ""){
   WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.layout.webscreen);
   String htmlString = bundle.getString("keyDescription");
   webview.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8");`

Comment: String htmlString = bundle.getString("keyDescription"); Ther is the problem. Use "extras.getString" instead of "bundle.getString"

Comment: Thanks marc. Yes, you should be using extras.getString().

Answer (score 0):

first:
Your if-Statment is wrong. It would be "false" at every run. You have to use "||" instead of "&&". The problem is that your URL String could only be "null" or empty.

second:
You can get your "keyDescription" with following statment in your second activity:

```
String keyDescription = savedInstanceState.getString("keyDescription");
```

Comment: Whenever I do this, it says savedInstanceState is unresolved.  I put it here:
`public static final String URL = "";
 private static final String TAG = "WebscreenClass";
 String keyDescription = savedInstanceState.getString("keyDescription");`

Comment: No, please insert my Statment above in the "onCreate" method. ;)